# MySQL - Auto Increment with Prefix as Primary Key on insert

Tags: mysql

`MI_TEST_ID | MI_TESTNAME | MI_DATE_CREATED | MI_FLAG |`

I've tried to make a trigger BEFORE INSERT but it's not working. Is it possible to make an auto increment with trigger before insert?

There's a built-in auto increment in MySQL but I want my test ID has a prefix like MI001 and so on.

```
  BEGIN 
INSERT INTO `mi_test` VALUES (NULL);
SET NEW.mi_test_id = CONCAT('MI', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'))
```

END

This is the trigger I used directly in the phpmyadmin trigger function. Whenever I try to insert. It always says column count does not match value count at row 1

I've looked solution in other thread, I found one of it requires another table for sequencing, but I need it on 1 query.

Answer (score 1):

You can find current auto_increment value that is to be assigned to a new record.
And use the same in the before trigger as a parent user id for user_records table.
You have to query information_schema.tables table to find the value.

Example:

```
use `gknet`;

delimiter $$

drop trigger if exists before_create_user; $$

create definer=`root`@`localhost` trigger `before_create_user` 
       before insert on `users` 
for each row begin
  declare fk_parent_user_id int default 0;

  select auto_increment into fk_parent_user_id
    from information_schema.tables
   where table_name = 'users'
     and table_schema = database();

  insert into user_records ( action, userid, timestamp )
         values ( 'created', fk_parent_user_id, now() );
end;

$$

delimiter ;
```